# How do I access my variable from a different file?

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to access my variable `$score` from a different file but I keep getting an error message.

I've already tried adding global to it to make it a global variable and I've tried it without global.

My current code is below (not the whole files just a bit)

**process.php** file (lines 29 -34)

```
if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
    global $score;
    $_SESSION['score']++;
    $score = $score++;
}
```

**final.php file** (lines 36 - 30)

### You are Done!

Congrats! You have completed the test

Final score:

Take Test Again

I want the score users received in their quiz to display on the screen, however right now the error I keep getting is
'Notice: Undefined variable: score in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpstaff\quiz\final.php on line 30
T'
Line 30 is `<?php echo $score; ?>`

In case you're wondering, I've already included `<?php session_start(); ?>` to both files and `$_SESSION['score']` seems to be working fine.

Comment: Where are you including process.php?

Comment: you can use $_SESSION to access your var from different files ,

Comment: oh I didn't include it, also I'm a bit confused as to how you use $S_SESSION

Comment: I added ``   <?php include "process.php" ?>  `` but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: `$score = $_SESSION['score'];
$score++;`
Just do this